# Expected convolution2d_input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape error in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running the following code snippet in keras as tensorflow backhend.

Network architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode="same",input_shape=(numChannels,imgRows, imgCols)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.fit(trainData, trainLabels, batch_size=batch_size,nb_epoch=20, verbose=verbose)
```

I get an error as:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected convolution2d_input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (89696, 1024)

How to fix this?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

`trainData` is not formatted correctly it should have shape `(numImages, numChannels, imgRows, imgCols)`.